# Windows: Notification when child dies (crash or exits normally)

Tags: windows, process

I am trying to figure out when a child process (created with CreateProcess() on Windows) crashes or exits normally. I am porting Unix code to Windows and have a lot of issue with this.

I use a SIGCHLD on Unix, as such:

```
struct sigaction act;
bzero(&act, sizeof(act));
act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &act, 0);

void sig_handler(int signal)
{
    int pid, status;

    if (signal == SIGCHLD) {
        while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &status, WNOHANG)) > 0) {
            // Remove pid from a data structure
        }
    }
}
```

I was looking at the solution of creating a new thread that calls WaitForMultipleObjects but the issue is that new processes can be created at any time, and I don't think I can interrupt WaitForMultipleObjects  when a new process gets created. I don't want to spawn a new thread for each process that has WaitOnSingleObject (I'd prefer to pull in a single thread if I have to).

What is the best solution in this case please?

Comment: What do you mean by "best?"

Comment: I would like to achieve the behavior above if possible: main thread or one thread, gets interrupted when child process crashes or terminates normally, for all child processes. That would be my most ideal case please.

Comment: Use RegisterWaitForSingleObject. That registers a function to be called when the handle is signaled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is a way to interrupt `WaitForMultipleObjects()`. Create a designated manual-reset event object using `CreateEvent()`. Include the event handle to `WaitForMultipleObjects()` along with your existing child process handles. Signal the event with `SetEvent()` each time a new child process is created. This way, `WaitForMultipleObjects()` exits whenever a child process exits (for whatever reason) or the event is signaled, then you can update the list of handles as needed, reset the event with `ResetEvent()`, and call `WaitForMultipleObjects()` again.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! This is a great solution for me.

Comment: Note that WaitForMultipleObjects has a maximum of 64 handles, so if you can have more than 63 child processes, you will need to break it up into chunks of 63. Or you can just use RegisterWaitForSingleObject which does all this for you.

Comment: That's an important consideration I did not know. Thanks!

Comment: I got it all implemented and working, this is great :) Very clear, thanks!